# Add text to cell when Check box ticked

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im looking to expand on the below formula, ive managed to get it to work for a single cell check box but what i want to achecive is when multiple check boxes are checked they all add the text into one cell. So if i check boxes 1,3,5 i want the text for those to be entered into Cell E1.

The formula i have presently which will populate the text in the adjacent box is

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B3),"",IF(B3,"Advised",""))
```

The formula i have tried to use to get the text into the one cell is below but this doesnt populate all of the selections selected.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",IF(B2,"Cover Confirmed",IF(B3,"Advised",)))
```

Any ideas on where i have gone wrong on this and can anyone show me what the formula is supposed to look like?
However this

Comment: Use `TEXTJOIN()`

Comment: Could you provide an example on how and where i would add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could toss individual `IF` formulas into a `TEXTJOIN`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, IF(OR(NOT(B2), B2=""), "", "checkbox 1 is checked"), IF(OR(NOT(B3), B3=""), "", "checkbox 2 is checked"), IF(OR(NOT(B4), B4=""), "", "Checkbox 3 is checked"))
```

You may find it "nicer" to use `MAP()` to manage this as well since if you want to add a 4th checkbox you only have to edit two spots. Also, if you want to edit the `if()` logic to be more complex, you only have to edit it once:

```
 =TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, MAP(TRANSPOSE(B2:B4), {"checkbox 1 is checked","checkbox 2 is checked","checkbox 3 is checked"}, LAMBDA(x,y,IF(OR(x="", NOT(x)), "",y))))
```